# Visual Basic 6 Image conversion from GIF to JPG or TIF

Tags: image-processing, vb6, jpeg

Language Visual Basic 6.

I want to know if there is an open source or existing Microsoft Image library that will 
allow me to convert a GIF (8 Bit Depth) image to either one of the following: JPG, TIF.

I am currently using Imaging for Windows V2.7 API. I only found recently it does't support all the GIF type images.

I found that 99% of the GIF images get processed with no issue. Please note that the image is not broken and I am able to open it with a other imaging tool.

Thank you.

Comment: Please note that I am using Outlook.Attachment.SaveAsFile (fullPathToSaveTo). It is when outlook saves the attachment it becomes invalid.

It must be the way in which Outlook saves GIF images when using the API.

The GIF opens 100% prior going through Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is an excellent free open source image manipulation package. There is an [OLE (ActiveX) control](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/ImageMagickObject.php) which you could use from VB6. I've never tried it myself - I always use the ImageMagick command line. I understand the control just takes the normal command lines anyway.

The [conversion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/) command for gif to jpg would be something like this.

```
convert my.gif my.jpg
```

EDIT: ImageMagick is licensed under the GPL: if you use the control and redistribute your program, it's possible your program would have to be free open-source. [Apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Linking_and_derived_works) it's not yet been legally tested whether dynamic linking to a GPL library or control invokes the GPL. You could always launch the ImageMagick command-line which to me should be safe [I am not a lawyer].

Comment: If have found that the VB6 PictureBox saves a loaded image in a JPEG or BMP based on the extension. So what I did is to Load the image using PictureBox and save the image with .JPG extension.

Comment: @Koekiebox.  Sorry, but once you load an image into a PictureBox control, SavePicture method will only save the picture as a BMP regardless of the extension. See my post on the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I've using [this](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/vbMedia/Saving_Pictures_to_JPG/Using_Intel_JPG_Library/article.asp) method using Intel's JPEG library.  It will help you save your PictureBox as a JPEG.  I am using this method in a production application and it works great.

Comment: Intel's JPEG library requires a specific license from Intel, and they do not appear to offer new licenses for this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [Windows® Image Acquisition Automation Library v2.0 Tool: Image acquisition and manipulation component for VB and scripting](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29&displaylang=en).  There are plenty of examples of using it for image conversion, Google should turn up quite a few.

Comment: It's only supported on Windows XP though.

Comment: But it is preinstalled as part of the OS on modern versions of Windows.

Comment: oh! +1 then. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: If you want documentation you'll want the Windows SDK, v 6.0 or later, or you can browse at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630827(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use ***GDIPlus*** library! It's Windows's standart library.
It converts to JPG , BMP , ICO and even to PNG, Transparent PNG and so on...
Try googling ***Convert images using GDIPlus library***.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [this awesome code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=50065&lngWId=1) for 6 years with never a problem