# Visual Basic 6: Tif Page convert from compression type ZLW, JPEG etc to Group4

Tags: vb6, image-processing

Does anyone know of an open source library in Visual Basic 6 that converts pages in a TIF file from lets say LZW to Group4 format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333901/visual-basic-6-image-conversion-from-gif-to-jpg-or-tif/1334441#1334441) of my answer to your other question!

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is an excellent free open source image manipulation package. There is an [OLE (ActiveX) control](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/ImageMagickObject.php) which you could use from VB6. I've never tried it myself - I always use the ImageMagick command line. I understand the control just takes the normal command lines anyway.

The command-line element for changing the TIFF format would be [-compress](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress). Something like this below to write in Group4 format ([air code](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2005/02/27/56126.aspx) based on [tutorial](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_gzip) and [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress))

```
convert myfile.tiff -compress Group4 myGroup4file.tiff
```

Choices for the -compress argument qualifier include: `None`, `Group4`, and `LZW`.

EDIT: ImageMagick is [licensed](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php) under the GPL: if you use the control and redistribute your program, it's possible your program would have to be free open-source. [Apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Linking_and_derived_works) it's not yet been legally tested whether dynamic linking to a GPL library or control invokes the GPL. You could always launch the ImageMagick command-line which to me should be safe [I am not a lawyer].

EDIT2: The ImageMagick website *says* it uses GPL but the license wording doesn't look like GPL 1 2 or 3 to me. It also contains this "For the purposes of this License, Derivative Works shall not include works that remain separable from, or merely link (or bind by name) to the interfaces of, the Work and Derivative Works thereof"

Comment: My bad. I accidentally pasted a message from notepad without thinking. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The FreeImage library has worked well for me in the past.

http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/