# Resize an user upload photo to fit my picture box in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I'm developing a stock management project using VB 6.0. Now I would like to include a feature that allow user to upload photo of his item to my system. Then I want to save it into database. Besides, I would like to limit the photo size to 600*600. So when user upload a picture greater that 600*600 pix, then my system should auto resize the photo to fit my picture box. Can anyone help out ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no easy ways to do this. I will be taking advantage of side-effects of VB's standard controls. Take a form / UserControl / whatever, and stick on the following controls:

- Image control <imgPic>
- Image control <imgSize>
- PictureBox control <pctCanvas>

I have added <dlgOpen> just to create a file open dialogue.

<imgPic> is used simply to preview the picture. <imgSize> is used to easily get the width and height of the picture file in pixels (note that I am setting the form's ScaleMode property to vbPixels to make it easier to do thi). <pctCanvas>
 is purely used to allow me to resize the picture.

Add the following code:

```
Option Explicit

' Edit these if you change your mind about the photo size.
Private Const m_ksngMaxPixelsX       As Single = 600!
Private Const m_ksngMaxPixelsY       As Single = 600!

Private Sub cmdLoad_Click()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

    dlgOpen.Filter = "Picture Files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif"
    dlgOpen.ShowOpen

    UploadPicture dlgOpen.FileName

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.ScaleMode = vbPixels
    pbCanvas.ScaleMode = vbPixels

    imgPic.Width = m_ksngMaxPixelsX
    imgPic.Height = m_ksngMaxPixelsY

    imgSize.Visible = False

    pbCanvas.Visible = False
    pbCanvas.AutoRedraw = True

End Sub

' Get a new filename, based on the original. It will always be a BMP bitmap.
Private Function GetResizedFilename(ByRef the_sFilename As String) As String

    Dim nPosDot                 As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    nPosDot = InStrRev(the_sFilename, ".")
    GetResizedFilename = Left$(the_sFilename, nPosDot - 1) & "-resized.bmp"

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
End Function

Private Sub ProcessPicture(ByRef the_sFilename As String, ByRef out_sProcessedFilename As String)

    Dim sngPixelsX          As Single
    Dim sngPixelsY          As Single

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Get the size of our picture. Would have liked to have used a StdPicture object here, instead.
    Set imgSize.Picture = LoadPicture(the_sFilename)

    sngPixelsX = imgSize.Width
    sngPixelsY = imgSize.Height

    ' If at least one of height and width is too bix, resize the biggest value down to m_ksngMaxPixels? and resize the other value proportionally.
    If sngPixelsX > m_ksngMaxPixelsX Or sngPixelsY > m_ksngMaxPixelsY Then
        If sngPixelsX > sngPixelsY Then
            sngPixelsY = m_ksngMaxPixelsY * sngPixelsY / sngPixelsX
            sngPixelsX = m_ksngMaxPixelsX
        Else
            sngPixelsX = m_ksngMaxPixelsX * sngPixelsX / sngPixelsY
            sngPixelsY = m_ksngMaxPixelsY
        End If

        ' Resize the canvas so that the persistent bitmap is the same size as the final picture, and then paint our picture onto that canvas, resizing down.
        pbCanvas.Move 0!, 0!, sngPixelsX, sngPixelsY
        pbCanvas.PaintPicture imgSize.Picture, 0!, 0!, sngPixelsX, sngPixelsY

        ' Get a reference to the persistent bitmap.
        Set imgPic.Picture = pbCanvas.Image

        out_sProcessedFilename = GetResizedFilename(the_sFilename)
        SavePicture pbCanvas.Image, out_sProcessedFilename

    Else
        out_sProcessedFilename = the_sFilename
        Set imgPic.Picture = imgSize.Picture
    End If

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub SaveToDatabase(ByRef the_sProcessedFilename As String)

    Dim nFileNo             As Integer
    Dim abytPictureFile()   As Byte
    Dim nFileLen            As Long

    ' Open the file in binary mode, resize a byte array to fit the file's contents, load it into the array, and close the array.
    nFileNo = FreeFile
    Open the_sProcessedFilename For Binary As #nFileNo

    nFileLen = LOF(nFileNo)
    ReDim abytPictureFile(1 To nFileLen)
    Get #nFileNo, , abytPictureFile()

    Close #nFileNo

    '
    ' YOUR WORK INSERTED HERE
    '

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub UploadPicture(ByRef the_sFilename As String)

    Dim sProcessedFilename As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ProcessPicture the_sFilename, sProcessedFilename

    SaveToDatabase sProcessedFilename

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Mark Bertenshaw, thanks for your coding. It helps me a lot. By the way, I wonder why after I resize my photo, the size seems to increase.  
Before Resize:-
Dimensions: 1024 x 768
Size: 185kb

After Resize:-
Dimensions: 596 x 446
Size: 778kb  
Is there any other way to improve this?

Comment: I am guessing that you have loaded a JPEG or GIF file, both of which are compressed formats. Unfortunately, VB can only save in BMP format. You will have to convert the file back. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517205/how-to-convert-bmp-to-jpg-in-vb6

Answer (score -1):

```
// This will be your uploaded images folder
string target = Server.MapPath("~/ImageFolder" ); 

Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort thumbnailImageAbortDelegate =
    new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);  

foreach (UploadedFile file in RadUpload1.UploadedFiles)
{  
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(target, file.GetName()));  
    using (Bitmap originalImage = new Bitmap(file.InputStream))
    { 
        // Set the resize here. You can use a constant or set a function here.
        int width = 600;
        int height = 600; 
        using (Image thumbnail = originalImage.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, thumbnailImageAbortDelegate, IntPtr.Zero))   
        {   
            string thumbnailFileName = Path.Combine(target,
                string.Format("{0}_thumb{1}" ,  file.GetNameWithoutExtension(), file.GetExtension()));
            thumbnail.Save(thumbnailFileName);   
        }   
    } 
}
```

Comment: That looks like C# - not VB6.