# VB6 converting to Jpeg with references from a paste

Tags: image, vb6, bitmap, jpeg

I am trying to paste a picture into the app and convert right away from a bitmap to a jpeg. I had it working before but then the Microsoft Image Acquisition dll is not possible for some of the computers the app will be used on. I found code to modify it to do this:

If Clipboard.GetFormat(vbCFMetafile) Or Clipboard.GetFormat(vbCFBitmap) Then
        strFileName = Format(Now, "ddhhmmss")

```
    If Clipboard.GetFormat(vbCFMetafile) Then
        SavePicture Clipboard.GetData(vbCFMetafile), strTemp & "\" & strFileName & ".bmp"
    Else
        Dim bm As Bitmap
        bm = Clipboard.GetData(vbCFBitmap)
        bm.Save strTemp & "\" & strFileName & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpg

    End If
    'UPLOAD to the DB

End If
```

However when I run the app it says variable not defined on the "System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpg, I have tried different combinations of Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpg and Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpg to no avail. I have added under Project -> References "System.Drawing.dll" but I don't know if I have to in this case import it or define it somewhere else.

Does anyone know how I could get this code to work, or a better way for me to make this conversion?

Comment: The application is in vb6.

Comment: But your `System.Drawing ...` is obviously .NET.

Comment: The Clipboard works I have used it before in this application.

Comment: However the System.Drawing .... may be .NET I am attempting to get it to work. Perhaps I'm not using Bitmap correctly in vb6?

Comment: Where does your `Bitmap` type come from? Also check out this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315840/can-vb6-save-an-image-as-a-jpeg

Comment: Yes I've looked into something like that but I cannot use that Image Acquisition DLL at this time.

Comment: Then you're probably better off disclosing _why_ you can't use it. Also do read comments to the question I pointed above too.